# Optimal joins in MySQL or offloading to application layer

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have 3 tables in a MySQL database: `courses`, `users` and `participants`, which contains about 30mil, 30k and 3k entries respectively.

My goal is to (efficiently) figure out the number of users that have been assigned to courses that matches our criteria. The criteria is a little more complex, but for this example we only care about users where `deleted_at` is `null` and courses where `deleted_at` is `null` and `active` is `1`.

Simplified these are the columns:

`users`:

| id | deleted_at |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 |

`courses`:

| id | active | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 0 | 2020-01-01 |

`participants`:

| id | participant_id | course_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

Based on the data above, the number we would get would be `1` as only user `1` is not deleted and that user assigned to *some* course (id 1) that is active and not deleted.

Here is a list of what I've tried.

- Joining all the tables and do simple `where`'s.
- Joining using subqueries.
- Pulling the correct courses and users out to the application layer (PHP), and querying `participants` using `WHERE IN`.
- Pulling everything out and doing the filtering in the application layer.
- Calling using EXPLAIN to add better indexes - I, admittedly, do not do this often and may not have done this well enough.
- A combination of all the above.

An example of a query would be:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT participant_id)
FROM `participants`
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT `courses`.`id`
   FROM `courses`
   WHERE (`active` = '1')
     AND `deleted_at` IS NULL) AS `tempCourses` ON `tempCourses`.`id` = `participants`.`course_id`
WHERE `participant_type` = 'Eloomi\\Models\\User'
  AND `participant_id` in
    (SELECT `users`.`id`
     FROM `users`
     WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)
```

From what I can gather doing this will create a massive table, which only then will start applying `where`'s. In my mind it should be possible to short circuit a lot of that because once we get a match for a user, we can disregard that going forward. That would be how to handle it, in my mind, in the application layer.

We could do this on a per-user basis in the application layer, but the number of requests to the database would make this a bad solution.

I have tagged it as PHP as well as MySQL, not because it has to be PHP but because I do not mind offloading some parts to the application layer if that is required. It's my experience that joins do not always use indexes optimally

**Edit:**
To specify my question: Can someone help me provide a efficient way to pull out the number of non-deleted users that have been assigned to to active non-deleted courses?

Comment: I don’t see a single question mark in your posting. Am i missing something?  If that was too subtle, what exactly are you asking for here?

Comment: It's not entirely clear exactly what you are asking here, if anything - are you after a specific query? Performance tuning the query above? Index tuning? What's the *assignments* table for - it's not even referenced in your query?

Comment: I am sorry. I have added an actual question. Also the lack of `assignments` table, is me (badly) trying to make it a bit more abstract, and messing it up when pasting in the query. An answer has been made using `participants` as the name, so I have renamed `assignments` to `participants` in the question, to make not subtract from the already given answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.participant_id)
FROM courses AS c 
INNER JOIN participants AS p
 ON c.id = p.course_id
INNER JOIN users AS u 
 ON p.participant_id = u.id
WHERE u.deleted_at IS NULL
 AND c.active = 1 AND c.deleted_at IS NULL
 AND p.participant_type = 'Eloomi\\Models\\User';
```

MySQL may join the tables in another order, not the order you list the tables in the query.

I hope that `courses` is the first table MySQL accesses, because it's probably the smallest table. Especially after filtering by `active` and `deleted_at`. The following index will help to narrow down that filtering, so only matching rows are examined:

```
ALTER TABLE courses ADD KEY (active, deleted_at);
```

Every index implicitly has the table's primary key (e.g. `id`) appended as the last column. That column being part of the index, it is used in the join to `participants`. So you need an index in `participants` that the join uses to find the corresponding rows in that table. The order of columns in the index is important.

```
ALTER TABLE participants ADD KEY (course_id, participant_type, participant_id);
```

The `participant_id` is used to join to the `users` table. MySQL's optimizer will probably prefer to join to `users` by its primary key, but you also want to restrict that by `deleted_at`, so you might need this index:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD KEY (id, deleted_at);
```

And you might need to use an index hint to coax the optimizer to prefer this secondary index over the primary key index.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.participant_id)
FROM courses AS c 
INNER JOIN participants AS p
 ON c.id = p.course_id
INNER JOIN users AS u USE INDEX(deleted_at)
 ON p.participant_id = u.id
WHERE u.deleted_at IS NULL
 AND c.active = 1 AND c.deleted_at IS NULL
 AND p.participant_type = 'Eloomi\\Models\\User';
```

MySQL knows how to use compound indexes even if some conditions are in join clauses and other conditions are in the WHERE clause.

Caveat: I have not tested this. Choosing indexes may take several tries, and testing the EXPLAIN after each try.

Comment: Thank you Bill. I believe I have tried something very similar to this, but without the use of `USE INDEX` which may actually be the key. I will give it a try later today.